# Changing div color on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to change the background-color of each div and make it stay that way once the mouse hovers over the div. Can't get it to change the color. What am I doing wrong? [Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/04uq1pnq/)

```
$('.container').on('hover', '#gridSquare', function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Couldn't you do this with css `:hover`?

Comment: I'm trying to do this project using mostly jQuery, so that would be my preferred method.

Comment: jQuery shouldn't be used for simple tasks such as changing the background. Especially if you can do this with css, it's less taxing on the page.

Comment: Using JQuery when you can one-line it in CSS is just overkill...

Comment: Your Id "gridSquare" is repeating.. You can see that on fiddle

Answer (score 9):

No need to use jQuery, just use css selector :hover

```
#gridSquare:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ud5s18n0/1/)

If you want to use jQuery, you need to use mouseenter and mouseleave

```
$('.container').on('mouseenter', '#gridSquare', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
}).on('mouseleave', '#gridSquare', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ud5s18n0/2/)

---

**Update**
As suggested below in the comments, ID of an element must be unique in a document so use class instead of id to group similar elements.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ud5s18n0/3/)

Comment: Thank you, but I want the grid to stay white after the mouse leaves the grid.

Comment: I used your jQuery method but I just removed the mouseleaved function. Thank you for the help again!

Comment: why not mention something on the bad practice of having multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: @sickcodeworm http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ud5s18n0/4/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ud5s18n0/4/

Answer (score 2):

You have elements with the same `id` in DOM. You can use `class` instead and css `:hover`. No need to use jquery here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var suareside = 16;
  var height = 40;
  var width = 40;

  $('.container').height(height * suareside);
  $('.container').width(width * suareside);

  for (var rows = 0; rows < width; rows++) {
    $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
    for (var cols = 0; cols < height; cols++) {
      $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
    }
  }
  //No need jquery
  /*$('.container').on('hover', '.gridSquare', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
  });*/

});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.gridSquare {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
/*change background on hover using css*/

.container .gridSquare:hover {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Made few changes to your js as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/04uq1pnq/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var suareside = 16;
    var height = 40;
    var width = 40;

    $('.container').height(height*suareside);
    $('.container').width(width*suareside);

    for(var rows = 0; rows < width; rows++){
    $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
        for(var cols = 0; cols < height; cols++){
            $('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
        }
    }

    $('.container').on('mouseover', '.gridSquare', function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });

});
```

- `id`s in DOM should be **unique**. So change it to `class`
- Use `mouseover` instead!

Answer (score 0):

You can use hover() for this.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var suareside = 16;
        var height = 40;
        var width = 40;

        $('.container').height(height*suareside);
        $('.container').width(width*suareside);

        for(var rows = 0; rows < width; rows++){
        $('<div id="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
            for(var cols = 0; cols < height; cols++){
                $('<div id="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container')
            }
        }

        $('.container').hover(function(){
            $('#gridSquare').css("background-color","#FFFFFF");
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your fiddle,

You have created div(s) with the same "id" attribute :

```
$('<div id="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container');
```

It will be better approach to use "class" instead of "id" :

```
$('<div class="gridSquare"></div>').appendTo('.container');
```

And to change the color of div(s) on mouseover:

If you are using gridSquare as "id":

```
$('.container').on('mouseover', '#gridSquare', function(){

            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');

});
```

If you are using gridSquare as "class":

```
$('.container').on('mouseover', '.gridSquare', function(){

            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');

});
```